# Don't understand Ruby ljust/rjust/center methods

Tags: ruby

I'm learning the nesting and my task is to make each new line start with an indent. Here's my code, but it doesn't work

```
$nestingDepth = 0

def logger description, &block
    puts "Beginning #{description}".rjust($nestingDepth)
    puts $nestingDepth
    $nestingDepth = $nestingDepth + 10
    result = block.call
    $nestingDepth = $nestingDepth - 10
    puts $nestingDepth
    puts "End of #{description} block that returned #{result}".rjust($nestingDepth)
end

logger "first block" do 
    logger "second block" do
        logger "third block" do 
            puts "third block part"
        end
        puts "second block part"
    end
    puts "first block part"
end
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to calls to puts to be indented?

Comment: How does it not work? What did you expect to happen? Your `$nestingDepth` seems to be de-/incremented just fine?

Comment: @JakobS yes, but the output is sticked to the left side of the terminal, just no indent

Comment: @britishtea I want the first block to have indent at all, the second one to have a little and the third one to have the biggest indent. And then as the blocks are finishing I want indent to become smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that [`rjust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-rjust) requires an integer greater than the length of the string it's applied on.  Your string is:

```
"Beginning #{description}"
```

Which turns into:

```
Beginning first block
Beginning second block
```

On most passes this is either a length of 21 or 22.  The largest you ever make `$nestingdepth` is 20.  When the integer is less than the length of the string it just returns the string with no padding. If I start the script with a nesting depth of 25 you see it unfold.

```
                             Beginning first block
25
                                      Beginning second block
35
                                                 Beginning third block
45
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code has several problems:

- you are using global variables which is generally a bad idea, pass it down as an argument instead. To do this you can use a `DSL` class that defines the logger and log methods.
- you are calling `puts` inside the blocks, but you never changed the definition of it, I don't see how you were expecting it to print an indented string, it will just print the string normally without indentation. For this to work you need to define a special method that prints with indentation, e.g. `log`
- you are calling `rjust` with the expectation that it will indent the string. This method has a different purpose - justifying a string to the right (i.e. left-padding it) with a specified length. If the string is longer than the specified length, the original string is returned. To actually indent a string you should do `puts ' ' * nestingDepth + string`. Looks magic at first, but the `*` operator just repeats the string, e.g. `'abc' * 3 #=> 'abcabcabc'`

All taken together I would do it like this:

```
class DSL
  def initialize
    @depth = 0
  end

  def logger(description, &block)
    log "Beginning #{description}"
    @depth += 1
    result = instance_eval(&block)
    @depth -= 1
    log "End of #{description} that returned #{result}"
  end

  def log(string)
    puts indent + string
  end

  private

  def indent
    ' ' * (10 * @depth)
  end
end

def logger(*args, &block)
  DSL.new.logger(*args, &block)
end
```

Example:

```
logger "first block" do 
  logger "second block" do
    logger "third block" do 
      log "third block part"
    end
    log "second block part"
  end
  log "first block part"
end
```

This prints:

```
Beginning first block
          Beginning second block
                    Beginning third block
                              third block part
                    End of third block that returned
                    second block part
          End of second block that returned
          first block part
End of first block that returned
```